# Update array when found same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

i have two array. And i want update second array with first array data if found same data.
Here is my first array :

```
var namaFile = [
            {
                billingID: "90009388",
                customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
                name: "201409011141106_082895250262"
            },
            {
                billingID: "90009400",
                customerID: "7885000000007804",
                name: "201410201141125_08287045931"
            },
            {
                billingID: "90009388",
                customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
                name: "201410011171208_082895250262"
            }
        ];
```

Here second array :

```
var emailAddr = [
            {
                customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
                email: "fanjavaid@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                customerID: "7885000000007804",
                email: "arrosyad.fikri@sampoernatelekom.com"
            }
        ];
```

Here is my code, but won't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < namaFile.length; i++) {
            var files = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr.length; j++) {
                if (namaFile[i].customerID == emailAddr[j].customerID) {
                    files.push(namaFile[i].name);
                    emailAddr[j]['files'] = files;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(emailAddr);
```

My expected result is like this :

```
var emailAddr = [
            {
                customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
                email: "fanjavaid@gmail.com",
                files : [
                    "201409011141106_082895250262","201410011171208_082895250262"
                ]
            },
            {
                customerID: "7885000000007804",
                email: "arrosyad.fikri@sampoernatelekom.com",
                files : [
                    "201410201141125_08287045931"
                ]
            }
        ];
```

How to create that result?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `for(...) {`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/p35zxb4g/)

```
for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr.length; j++) {
    var files = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < namaFile.length; i++) {
        if (namaFile[i].customerID == emailAddr[j].customerID) {
            files.push(namaFile[i].name);
            emailAddr[j]['files'] = files;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`emailAddr[j]['files'] = files;`by this line you are overwriting `emailAddr[j]['files']` each times

```js
var namaFile = [{
  billingID: "90009388",
  customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
  name: "201409011141106_082895250262"
}, {
  billingID: "90009400",
  customerID: "7885000000007804",
  name: "201410201141125_08287045931"
}, {
  billingID: "90009388",
  customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
  name: "201410011171208_082895250262"
}];

var emailAddr = [{
  customerID: "C20121121221327_249",
  email: "fanjavaid@gmail.com"
}, {
  customerID: "7885000000007804",
  email: "arrosyad.fikri@sampoernatelekom.com"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < namaFile.length; i++) {
  var files = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < emailAddr.length; j++) {
    if (emailAddr[j]['files'] == null)
      emailAddr[j]['files'] = [];
    if (namaFile[i].customerID == emailAddr[j].customerID) {
       
      emailAddr[j]['files'].push(namaFile[i].name);
    }
  }
}

console.log(emailAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use underscore js which can be a good option for you if you have lot of object/data manipulation in your code.

and then your code may look like:

`_.each(emailAddr, function(customer) {
    var files = _.where(namaFile, {customerID: customer.customerID});
    customer.files = _.map(files, function(file) {
        return file.name;
    });
});`